# como crear un input type='button' en jade?

Tags: jade, botón

Tengo este codigo pero cuando le doy click no hace redirecciona. ¿Qué puedo hacer?

```
input.waves-effect.waves-light.btn-large.red.accent-3(type='button', onclick=location="'../formulario.html'", value="Registrarse")
```

Comment: no deberia ser asi: onclick=location='../formulario.html'

Comment: lo puse asi pero igual no redirecciona como si no fuera un botton

Comment: talves la falla es en el arbol , prueba con un solo ".", asi: './formulario.html'

Comment: a.waves-effect.waves-light.btn-large.red.accent-3(type="button", href="../formulario.html", value="registrarse") lo puse asi pero no me muestra el value del botton

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El error esta en donde has puesto las comillas aquí:

```
onclick=location="'../formulario.html'"
```

Prueba hacerlo así:

```
onclick="location='../formulario.html'"
```

El codigo completo sería:

```
input.waves-effect.waves-light.btn-large.red.accent-3(type='button', onclick="location='../formulario.html'", value="Registrarse")
```

Comment: muchas gracias eso me funciono

Answer (score 0):

no deberia ser asi:

> onclick=location='../formulario.html'

```
tal vez la falla es en el arbol , prueba con un solo ".", asi: './formulario.html'
```

o prueba con

> onclick="location='../formulario.html'"